# Replace certain dates with NA

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I'm trying to replace certain dates with NA.

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
df <- data.frame(dates = seq.Date(as.Date("1910-01-01"), as.Date("1999-01-01"), "days")) %>%
       mutate_if(dates < as.Date("1990-01-05"),NA)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like `%>% mutate_if(is.date, funs(replace(., . < as.Date("1990-01-05"), NA)))` where `is.date <- function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')`

Comment: @akrun - using `base::replace()` was the key difference for me. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the if of mutate_if applies to columns. you just need a normal mutate:

```
df <- data.frame(dates = seq.Date(as.Date("1910-01-01"), as.Date("1999-01-01"), "days")) %>%
     mutate(newdates=ifelse(dates < as.Date("1990-01-05"), dates ,NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using `mutate`, you can also simply assign the dates greater than your target date to `NA` using:

```
df$dates[df$dates < as.Date("1990-01-05")] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you, I prefer the mutate version though as there follow on operations on this column too