# How to change date value in R?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have this data frame which I imported in R just with the times and it automatically added the dates and is in this format:

```
 horidat$CORD4
 [1] "1899-12-31 06:25:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 06:45:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 07:00:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 07:15:00 UTC"
 [5] "1899-12-31 07:30:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 07:45:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 07:57:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 08:09:00 UTC"
 [9] "1899-12-31 08:21:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 08:32:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 08:43:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 08:54:00 UTC"
```

And i wanted tho change only the the date `1899-12-31` into a different one, like `2010-01-25`. They are in POSIXct format.

Could you tell me how to do it, if it is even possible?

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397196/replace-certain-dates-with-na

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it (in `base R`)

```
paste('2010-01-25', format(as.POSIXct(horidat$CORD4), '%T'))
# [1] "2010-01-25 06:25:00" "2010-01-25 06:45:00"

# or with (local) time zone
paste('2010-01-25', format(as.POSIXct(horidat$CORD4), '%T %Z')) # or %z for digits
# [1] "2010-01-25 06:25:00 CET" "2010-01-25 06:45:00 CET" # (I'm in a different time zone)

# or keeping the class POSIXct
as.POSIXct(paste('2010-01-25', format(as.POSIXct(horidat$CORD4), '%T')))
# [1] "2010-01-25 06:25:00 CET" "2010-01-25 06:45:00 CET"
```

with the data

```
horidat <- data.frame(CORD4 = c('1899-12-31 06:25:00 UTC','1899-12-31 06:45:00 UTC'), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi nate, 
Thank you very much!
The first part seems to be working.

But I think i'm not understanding this part the last part with the date, that would only make horidat a data frame with two values right? How do apply the past to the date frame?

Comment: @Hanna the last part (`horidat <- ...`) is simply a *sample* for other users to be able to reproduce the code. (Since you already have the data `horidat`, just ignore the second part)

Comment: Sorry nate, i have another question, do you know how can i keep the POSIXct format? after doing this it assumes the character format, my idea after would be to calculate time differences with other data frame and columns after this conversion. Thank you.

Comment: @Hanna Just use `as.POSIXct` - see my edit in the answer (method 3).